# Can one tour a cruise ship in Sydney?

Tags: tours, cruising, sydney

Every day at the moment there are several companies docking their cruise ships in Sydney Harbour.

They're usually there for at least the day, and what I'm wondering is - is it possible to go aboard, free or paid - to see what one looks like on the inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security rules prohibit casual visitors entering a cruise ship while in port, for same security reasons that keep folks from wandering into an aircraft parked at an airport.  But as always there are exceptions ....

Travel agents can pre-arrange to inspect a ship when it is in port, but this comes with strings attached, such as the volume of business your agency has sent to that cruise line, being escorted around the ship by a crew member, restrictions as to which ports this is possible, etc

Some cruise lines and/or ports allow family members onboard during initial boarding at the port of embarkation.  But not usually at stops during the cruise.

Comment: Hmm, good tip re travel agents, I have a friend who works for one in Melbourne, may have to ask her next time she's in Sydney checking out a ship.

Comment: Tagging along is not likely.  She will need to request permits for you when she requests hers and may have to prove you also work for the agency (id card, business card, letter from t.a. owner, etc).  Even as a travel professional who has a legitimate need to inspect ships for inclusion in tour programs, I have to jump through hoops and get told NO as often as YES.

Comment: @Tom...curses.  Well it's my best shot I guess. Thanks!